# How to use python into an existing php web application?

Tags: python, php, codeigniter

I am currently working on a php web application built with codeigniter 3 framework.
I am planning to use python in this application
Please explain me the best method to achieve this!

I was thinking like creating a REST api with python django and connect it from php backend. Would that be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible.

```
$r=shell_exec("python3 mypythonscript.py"); 
echo $r;
```

you can run your API using .py file.
And add it to your PHP project using this code.
[For more check this url](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/php/frameworks/codeigniter/php+run+python+script)